# Reactjs why does removing notes (items in array) cause all the content to shift position

Tags: reactjs

I am working on this hobby project of creating sticky notes, by clicking on the x on the notes, you can see the note doesn't disappear as expected but the contents inside that note is gone but the rest of the notes also change, why is that, this is the link to codesanbox, thanks!!
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hugle-1o2o2

Comment: I think it is working. I just re-orders the list after updating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `key` for each item when rendering arrays of elements.

Read https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for more details.

Here is a fix to your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-snow-yqitv

Basically add a key when creating a new note and use it when rendering the items.

```
  add = note => {
    var temp = this.state.notes;
    temp.push({ key: Math.random().toString(), note });
    this.setState({ notes: temp });
  };
```

---

(*the example code just uses `Math.random` to generate the key, which is not safe for production use. See https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid#readme for a better approach*)

You might also want to review your code to not mutate the state.

Comment: Thanks a million, Gabriele! First post in StackOverflow and been scratching my head for ages, thanks for the prompt solution!